# How to assign selected value to "Test" variable in <select> control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have code like

```
<div>
        <%
            int Test;

            Test = 10;
        %>
    </div>
<select id="list">
    <option value="30">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
</select>
```

i need assign value to "Test" variable while when i am changing value in `<select>` control.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. The `Test` variable exists only server side whereas the `<select>` change event occurs only on the client side. So if you want to subscribe for the change event of the select box you need to use javascript.